# How to use Windows system image to restore ONLY one partition (the one imaged)

Tags: windows-7, backup, system-restore, disk-image

Here's my hard disk layout:

One ~200MB HDD: 4 Partitions

1. EFI (200MB)
2. OS X 10.11 (74GB)
3. Windows 7 (98GB)
4. Backup (23GB)

I'm trying to use a Windows 7 system image, which I have on my /dev/disk0s4 to restore my /dev/disk0s3 partition...

I'm getting an error saying that I can't because the image is on the same physical drive as the partition being restored. But, most importantly, my OS X partition needs to be left untouched, and I fear that Windows wants to wipe the entire drive. I also tried first to restore from a flash drive, but I got an I/O error from two separate models.  What can I do?

Comment: Windows system image is a limited software, it can only be restored as a whole disk image unfortunately. Restore the image to another drive then use 3rd party image software to capture the partition you need,

Comment: Can I use the System Protection restore points? Or will that also require the entire disk to be wiped?

Comment: Yes, restore points do not disturb user data.